# How to know which volume stream is being used?

Tags: android

As many of you might know, Android has many volume streams such as:

```
STREAM_ALARM        The audio stream for alarms
STREAM_DTMF         The audio stream for DTMF Tones
STREAM_MUSIC        The audio stream for music playback
STREAM_NOTIFICATION The audio stream for notifications
STREAM_RING         The audio stream for the phone ring
STREAM_SYSTEM       The audio stream for system sounds
STREAM_VOICE_CALL   The audio stream for phone calls
```

I would like to know which volume stream is being used currently. I have tried using getMode() method in the Audio Manager class but it returns irrelevant information.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
Register a receiver for action : android.media.VOLUME_CHANGED_ACTION
and check for extra value of "EXTRA_VOLUME_STREAM_TYPE" in onReceive
```